# Undefined array.lenght when passed as an argument to a function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameter-passing

In the below code function `GetRandomInt` takes an input max from function `App`. The supposed output `console.log` should just print the argument value. But it prints out Undefined in the console.

```js
const GetRandomInt = ({max}) => {
  console.log(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max))
}


const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
      {props.text}
    </button>
  )
}

const Display = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.text}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const anecdotes = [
    'If it hurts, do it more often',
    'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
    'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 10 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
    'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
    'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
    'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.',
    'Programming without an extremely heavy use of console.log is same as if a doctor would refuse to use x-rays or blood tests when diagnosing patients'
  ]
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const len = anecdotes.length
  console.log(len)
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (anecdotes.length)))
    const index = GetRandomInt(len) // Math.floor(Math.random() * (anecdotes.length))
    while (index === selected) {
      index = GetRandomInt(len) // Math.floor(Math.random() * (anecdotes.length))
    }
    setSelected(index)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Anecdote of the day</h1>
      <Display text={anecdotes[selected]} />
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} text={'Next anecdote'} />
      {/* {anecdotes[selected]} */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The above code prints three values to the console

1. assigned variable that contains array length
2. Direct usage of array length to create a random integer
3. Passed value to function to achieve the same in step 2 using function

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Am I passing the value incorrectly either datatype mismatch or something? I am a newbie in reactjs and learning through a course and this is one of the exercises where I am stuck.

Comment: Right now, clicking the **Run code snippet** button just throws up a syntax error. Please edit the snippet so it successfully runs, demonstrating the problem. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: We can't help you without seeing `GetRandomInt`, where the problem apparently is. `len` will definitely be `array.length` in the code that's currently in the question.

Comment: @Andy I understand that. But I wanted to know why passing the number is resulting in undefined in my code. I want to know my mistake so that I won't repeat it again. Thank for the suggestion though.

Comment: **It's basically a typo.** You're using `{max}` (destructuring) in the parameter list of `GetRandomInt`, which means you're trying to use the `max` property on the number you pass in. That will give you `undefined`, as numbers don't have `max` properties. Remove the `{}` in the parameter list.

Comment: So much easier to shuffle the array and pop off than looping over and over again so you get a different index.

Comment: @Andy - Although that would result in the message changing if the parent re-rendered for reasons not related to this component, whereas the above won't change messages unless you click. (Unless the OP memo-izes the component above.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So if I have let's say two arguments to pass to function should I use curly braces for that or no. I am kinda confused now.

Comment: @sajankumar - If you have two arguments to pass the function, declare two parameters. (`const x = (first, second) => { /*...*/ };`). You only use destructuring with objects (including arrays, sometimes). I suggest reading [MDN's coverage of destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (or my book, Chapter 7; links in my profile). If you're unsure about how parameters and arguments work, they should be covered fairly early in any good tutorial. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the clarity. One last question what's the difference between using props and directly passing the argument?

Comment: @sajankumar - "Props" is a React (and similar) thing where they pass the properties specified for the element as an object as the only argument to the function. But that's just that one use case; functions in general can have multiple parameters (which can be objects or not). Props are just a single use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw is in your `GetRandomInt` function. It currently expects an object with the `max` property, and you are passing a number to it.

Rewrite it as

```js
const GetRandomInt = (max) => {
  console.log(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max))
}
```

What the curly braces around the parameter name essentially do is telling the function "Take the property `max` of the first argument you are given", while in your case you want the argument itself, and not its `max` property.

You can read more about object destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)